# C# Reports: System x64 Bug

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

This is a `C#` project and  I am using `combit.ListLabel20 : v20.2.5520.28805` module.

My project is too old and won't remove major changes. So I have to fix the problem with minimal change.

In `x86` mode everything works fine and always stable.

But I can't find enough **RAM Space** for **x86** anymore. That's why we upgraded to `x64`. However, one of the plugins (**ListLabel**) did not give an error, but it does not create a new instance.

In the 1st line I have added the breakpoint below, it does not create a new instance and does not move to the 2nd line and the program does not react at all.

No error code
my computer is x64
I have all the necessary dll files and packages.
no stacktrace

My question is: How can a x86 `dll` be activated or used in a x64 project?

[image]

Comment: You can't load a 32-bit dll or assembly into a 64-bit process or vice versa. Typically you would run a separate process for your other bit-ness parts and have some inter-process communication method to pass data back and forth. This does not work for controls. If this `ListLabel` control is part of a 3rd party control library then I think this would be the time to hit up support on their end to get some help. Have you tried reducing the code down to a project that only uses this control, and if so, does that also have issues?

Comment: thanks we bought the new version which is 64bit and now project is AnyCpu and now i have new bugs but i have explained them under another topic.